# Customer request: daily report of the changes between two tables of DB

Tags: html, sql, report

today my customer made me a request: report to him the changes between two tables of our DB with daily reports.
Actually, I'm thinking what is the best (and smarter) way to do this.

- A SQL procedure?
- An HTML page?

I'm not sure how to do this. How can I mark the changes between two tables?
I'll try to explain better with an example:

```
YESTERDAY TABLE:

+----+----------+----------+-----------+----------------+
| ID | HOSTNAME |    IP    |  STATUS   |      NOTE      |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+----------------+
| 01 | TEST_HST |127.0.0.1 |  ACTIVE   |Lorem Ipsumm    |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+----------------+
| 02 | TST2_HST |10.6.10.1 |   DOWN    |Lorem Ipsumm    |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+----------------+
| 03 | TST3_HST |10.6.10.2 |  ACTIVE   |Lorem Ipsumm    |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+----------------+

TODAY TABLE

+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------------------------------+
| ID | HOSTNAME |    IP    |  STATUS   |     NOTE     |             TODAY_NOTES           |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------------------------------+
| 01 | TEST_HST |127.0.0.1 |   DOWN    |Lorem Ipsumm  |STATUS: DOWN                       |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------------------------------+
| 02 | TST2_HST |10.6.10.1 |  ACTIVE   |Bla bla bla   |STATUS: ACTIVE, NOTE: Bla bla bla  |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------------------------------+
| 03 | TST3_HST |10.6.10.2 |   DOWN    |Bla bla BLA   |STATUS: DOWN, NOTE; Bla bla BLA    |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------------------------------+
```

I want to make a report (in table form) to my customer that mark the differences between those two tables. What is the best possible way in your opinion?

Thanks to all for the support.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you the old and new values, how you display this data is up to you.

```
SELECT yt.*, tt.Status AS NewStatus, tt.Note AS NewNote 
FROM YesterdayTable yt
INNER JOIN TodaysTable tt
ON yt.ID = tt.ID
WHERE vt.Status <> tt.Status OR vt.Note <> tt.Note
```

This would give you:

```
+----+----------+----------+-----------+----------------+
| ID | HOSTNAME |    IP    |  STATUS   |      NOTE      |NewStatus | NewNote
+----+----------+----------+-----------+----------------+
| 01 | TEST_HST |127.0.0.1 |  ACTIVE   |Lorem Ipsumm    | DOWN     | Lorem Ipsum
+----+----------+----------+-----------+----------------+
| 02 | TST2_HST |10.6.10.1 |   DOWN    |Lorem Ipsumm    | ACTIVE   | Bla bla bla
+----+----------+----------+-----------+----------------+
| 03 | TST3_HST |10.6.10.2 |  ACTIVE   |Lorem Ipsumm    | DOWN     | Bla bla bla
+----+----------+----------+-----------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I should give evidence of the changes to my customer with (maybe) a column "Today Notes" with the found changes or putting in "bold" the fields changed. Any idea?

Comment: @l_core That sounds like a new question really. Both DB query and styling of the data shouldn't be in the same question/answer. You could add a sql data source to an excel sheet, run this query and format the last two columns as bold, as a quick sample. You could return this data to your html page as json, use a table plugin and add css styling to the last two columns. Depends on the requirement and how/where you want to display it.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. I don't think to this as two separate question. I mean, I need a "way" to make this kind of report, not a way to format the results. I need to put in evidence the modified data, adding a "verbose" note to my table or make in bold the new data. Thanks again for the collaboration.

Comment: @l_core I think the easiest way to see this data like I said would be in excel, running this query. So you can show your client what it looks like and go from there. Good luck.